# how to validate list of hostnames and IP

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed

we need to validate the list file

```
master01.sys65.com 23.154.3.61
master02.sys65.com 23.154.3.62
master03.sys65.com 23.154.3.63
worker01.sys65.com 23.154.3.64
worker02.sys65.com 23.154.3.65
worker03.sys65.com 23.154.3.66
kafka01.sys65.com  23.154.3.85
kafka02.sys65.com  23.154.3.86
kafka03.sys65.com  23.154.3.87
```

the rule is:

on each first field hostname must be in the second field  IP address

example of wrong list

```
master01.sys65.com 23.154.3.61
master02.sys65.com 23.154.3.62
master03.sys65.com 23.154.3.63
worker01.sys65.com 23.154.3.64
worker02.sys65.com 23.154.3.65
worker03.sys65.com 
kafka01.sys65.com  23.154.3.85
kafka02.sys65.com  23.154.3.86
kafka03.sys65.com  23.154.3.87


or

master01.sys65.com 23.154.3.61
master02.sys65.com 23.154.3.62
master03.sys65.com 23.154.3.63
worker01.sys65.com 23.154.3.64
worker02.sys65.com 23.154.3.65
23.154.3.66
kafka01.sys65.com  23.154.3.85
kafka02.sys65.com  23.154.3.86
kafka03.sys65.com  23.154.3.87
```

Comment: use regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/106223/1195001 for example. But what do you want to do ? validate the format ? or validate that your DNS currently matches the correct IP ? in the second case what have you try so far ?

Comment: Or just that there’s two columns?

Comment: yes file should be with two columns

Comment: What have you tried? https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NF == 1{ f=1; exit }END{ print "Hostname list is "(f? "not ":"")"valid" }' file
```